# Hiding a Tab when the View from Field View is Empty

Tags: views, entities

I'm using [Views Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field) to show a view in a Horizontal Tab in a content type. My trouble is that when the view returns empty based on filter criteria, the tab is not hidden.

The view itself has 4 fields from the content plus some custom text.

I tried going through [some of the "Not Empty" tips](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343430#comment-6434632) for hding blocks when views are empty, but It didn't work and it was all a shot in the dark anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$node = node_load($argument);
if ((isset($node->field_fotos) || 
     isset($node->field_summary)) &&
     (is_array($node->field_fotos) &&
     count($node->field_fotos) > 0) ||
     (is_array($node->field_summary) && 
     count($node->field_summary) > 0)) {
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Where would I try that? In the view or in the page template? Also I'm assuming `field_fotos` and `field_summary` would be replaced by my particular fields.